# Block IPs that requested more than N times per minute from a log file

Tags: bash, awk, iptables

I want to block IPs that requested more than N times/min using `iptables` .
I've sorted the log file using this script:
`cat $log_path | awk '{print $1, $4}' | sort -n -k 1,4 | sed "s/\[//g"`

```
10.200.3.120 20/May/2021:21:05:04
10.200.3.120 20/May/2021:21:05:17
10.200.3.120 20/May/2021:21:05:18
10.200.3.120 20/May/2021:21:05:19
10.200.3.120 20/May/2021:21:05:20
10.200.3.120 20/May/2021:22:05:39
104.131.19.181 20/May/2021:19:05:31
107.23.7.76 20/May/2021:20:05:16
119.252.76.162 20/May/2021:22:05:00
119.252.76.162 20/May/2021:22:05:01
119.252.76.162 20/May/2021:22:05:01
119.252.76.162 20/May/2021:22:05:04
119.252.76.162 20/May/2021:22:05:04
119.252.76.162 20/May/2021:21:05:10
119.252.76.162 20/May/2021:21:05:44
⋮
```

In the example log above, two IPs requested more than **4** times in a minute (`10.200.3.120`, `119.252.76.162`) and they should be blocked.
How can I get the number of requests in a time interval for each IP and block those IPs?

Comment: How do you block an IP?

Comment: @anubhava `iptables -A INPUT -s [IP] -j DROP`

Comment: ok can you show few lines of `$log_path` file?

Comment: The original file is like this: https://pasteboard.co/VqMElCKFMUiL.png but as I just wanted to see IPs & timestamps I've used that script in question.

Comment: But `10.200.3.120` is appearing only 3 times in a minute

Comment: that was a typo and didn't change the whole question, edited tho.

Comment: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @Rob: This question is about programming only using shell or awk. Configuring `iptables` is not part of question or answer.

Comment: @anubhava The question asks how to block the IPs in iptables.

Comment: @Rob: Don't just go by the title read the problem where OP wants to find a IP string from log file occurring in the same minute and wants to extract those IPs that occur more than 4 times in the same minute.

Comment: @anubhava I went by the question in the question. The last sentence. I may be using too sharp a knife.

Comment: OP's last sentence is `How can I get the number of requests in a time interval for each IP and block those IPs?`. It is definitely a programming problem, request you to please retract your close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution:

```bash
awk '
{
   gsub(/\[|:[0-9]+$/, "", $4)
   ++fq[$4,$1]
}
END {
   for (i in fq)
      if (fq[i] >= 4) {
         sub(".*" SUBSEP, "", i)
         print "iptables -A INPUT -s", i, "-j DROP"
      }
}' "$log_path" | sh
```

Here:

- `gsub` function strips starting `[` and seconds value from timestamp
- `++fq[$4,$1]` increments array element `fq` by 1 where each element is composite key `$4,$1` i.e. `$4 SUBSEP $1` string
- In the `END` block we loop through `fq` array. When `fq[i] >= 4` we remove starting text followed by SUBSEP from array index to leave only `IP`.
- Finally we print full `iptables` command line using the `ip` we just extracted
- Finally we pipe `awk` output to `sh` to run all commands

Answer (score 0):

You can block the ip like this :

```
iptables -A INPUT -s <ip-address-to-block> -j DROP
```

Adapt your bash script to use this command whenever you see an ip requesting more than you want. The idea is to read your log file with a given frequency and parse the number each ip appears. If it appears more than you want, you drop it.

To unblock the ip, you can use this
command:

```
iptables -D INPUT -s <ip-address-to-unblock> -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to get time intervals, an IP could appear more than N times but not requested N times in 1 MINUTE.